# javascript insertBefore() difficulties

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add rows to a table dynamically.  It is working fine with the following code:

```
var tableAdd = document.getElementById(tableChoice);
var lastRow = tableAdd.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var cloneRow = document.getElementById(RowID + '1');
var newRow = cloneRow.cloneNode(true);
newRow.id = RowID + lastRow;
tableAdd.appendChild(newRow);
```

However, because of the way it is designed, this leaves a gap between the  and the corresponding  rows in the rendered HTML.  This space is a hidden row to copy without copying the "data" inside it.

The solution I came up with is to basically send the whitespace below by inserting the cloned row above the hidden "template" row using the code below:

```
var tableAdd = document.getElementById(tableChoice);
var lastRow = tableAdd.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var cloneRow = document.getElementById(RowID + '1');
var newRow = cloneRow.cloneNode(true);
newRow.id = RowID + lastRow;
tableAdd.insertBefore(newRow,cloneRow);
```

And from all the searching I have done, that should work....except it doesn't.  It just freezes the application and then throws a cryptic error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NotFoundError
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you getting from cloneRow ?

Comment: It might be that `cloneRow` is not a child of `tableAdd` like it should be (because of implicitly created `<tbody>`s). MDN explains the method as: `parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)`. Try using `cloneRow.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, cloneRow);`

Comment: It may not found the `cloneRow` for reference.

Comment: Just remove the `cloneRow` from the table at the beginning of your script…

Comment: @Edorka - cloneRow returns a node with an id of swRow1 (where RowID is identified as 'swRow' - but I left that out as it is dynamically generated so sometimes RowID is one of several other strings such as fglRow, HSRow, etc.)

Comment: @Ian, That suggesting doesn't make much sense to me, but either does the error, so I am trying it now.  It returns the error:  "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference".  I am guessing it is because cloneRow is a child element of tableAdd and not a parent element, but as I am fairly new to this I may just not understand what is going on.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't quite follow what you are saying.  Are you saying delete the reference all together?  If so, then it won't clone anything and not create any new rows at all.

Comment: What about creating a jsfiddle?

Comment: Never heard of that before.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Well jsfiddle didn't help answer the question (it wouldn't even work there), but it did give me a good workaround via an accidental mistaken cut and paste.  I will just move the "header row" below the hidden row and replace the <th> tags with <td> tags and a class to apply the appropriate formatting.  It doesn't solve the question, but it does solve the problem.  Thanks to all for the suggestions.  I will continue to monitor for an actual solution.